# Finding number of electrons in n-type semiconductors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

I'm having numerical problem based on n-type semiconductors:

> Suppose a pure Si crystal has $\mathrm{5 \times 10^{28}\ m^{-3}}$. It is doped by $1$ ppm concentration of pentavalent As. Calculate the number of electrons and holes. Given, $\mathrm{n_i = 1.5 \times 10^{16} \ m^{-3}}$ ($\mathrm{n_i} =$ number of intrinsic charge carriers).

You can find the same numerical on the web and the solution too, like [here](https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/suppose-a-pure-si-crystal-has-5-10-28-atoms-m-3-it-is-doped/semiconductor-electronics/9897472),
but they are ridiculous.

My approach:

$1$ ppm = $1 \ g\ m^{-3}$

So, I decided to calculate the number of arsenic atoms present in $1 \ m^{3}$ of the silicon crystal. And I was hoping to get the correct answer, but no!

Book's approach:

$\mathrm{1 \  As \ atom\ in \ 10^{6} \ atoms \ of \ Si }$ (Right!)

$\mathrm{\frac{1}{10^{6}} \  As \ atom\ in \  1 \ atom \ of \ Si }$ (Right mathematics but Strange!)

So, in  $\mathrm{5 \times 10^{28}}$ atoms of silicon = $\mathrm{\frac{5 \times 10^{28}}{10^{6}}}$  atoms of arsenic (Yeah! right!)

But, my approach and book's approach aren't giving same results. I'm not convinced with book's solution. Please tell me what to do? This is where I'm standing still!

Comment: Ppm as w/w it is more straightforward than you assuming m/v. You have no water nor diluted solutions

Comment: That means book's correct? ah?

Comment: I didn't go through.  But 1 ppm of As in Si is surely 1mg in a kilogram or 1 atom every 10E6 (minus 1 to be precise:) )

Answer (score 1):

The text of the cited question is unclear. The first sentence is incomplete. It probably states the density of Si atoms in a Si crystal, which is $5 \times 10^{28}m^{-3}$. The concentration probably also refers to the relative number of As atom. You are right, relative concentrations are usually given as relative mass concentrations, but you should take the book's view. So you have a concentration of As atoms of $5 \times 10^{22}m^{-3}$. Assuming that they are all ionized, you have the same concentration of electrons $$n=5 \times 10^{22}m^{-3}$$and, according to the law of mass action $$np =n_i^2=(1.5 \times 10^{16}m^{-3})^2 $$ you get a hole concentration $$p= \frac {(1.5 \times 10^{16}m^{-3})^2}{5 \times 10^{22}m^{-3}}=4.5 \times 10^9 m^{-3}$$

Comment: Ok!, so it means i have to go with the books solution! Oh! i'm not satisfied!....by the way, thanks....your real name?

Comment: Besides the very simple calculations,  dopant concentration is usually given as n/n. The book is very standard like, in this sense.  Point to be precise:  there is nothing ionised in there.

Comment: @Alchimista -You should know that dopants like As in Si can either be neutral, meaning that the the donor energy level in the bandgap is occupied by an electron  or they can be ionized , when they have given (donated)  their fifth valence electron to the conduction band. The latter occurs at high enough temperatures. The donor As in Si has an ionization energy of  0.054 eV which is the energy required to move the electron from the donor level in the bandgap to the conduction band edge.

Comment: Ok if  onecconsider the doping center an ion. What is the meaning of "assuming that they are all ionized" then? Is there is open possibility for a As atom simply be frozen as impurity without interacting with the lattice?

Comment: @Alchimista - The number (or probability) of donors being occupied by the fifth valence electron (and thus neutral)  or alternatively being not occupied by an electron (and thus ionized) is determined by Fermi-Dirac statistics. The As atoms are usually replacing a Si atom in the Si lattice. See any book on semiconductor physics. E.g. S.M.  Sze, Semiconductor Devices -  Physics and Technology,  John Wiley & Sons, 2nd ed., 2002

Comment: You cannot assign the electrons you distribute via FD to any specific atom no As nor S. Just to the lattice. I see you use ionized for those As corresponding in number to the electrons promoted (T) to the conduction band

Comment: S stands for Si. In such a sense might be common to call for ionisation in solid state chemistry and physics (likely it is). It seemed anyway over the level of the Q. It is suggesting the existence of oppositely ionized Si atoms. My major point to OP there is no need to go to d as m/V as the data are given explicitely.

Comment: @ Alchimista -Please consult a book. In Si you have non-localized states of electrons in the conduction band and localized electron states at donors (As) that are occupying Si lattice points. The occupation statistics of these discrete electron states is basically a FD distribution with a single chemical potential. A specific As atom  can give  one of its valence electrons to the conduction band so that a positively charged (+e) ion core remains at the site. This ion core can "catch" a conduction electron so that it is bound to the ion core like in a hydrogen atom. Then the donor is neutral.